# Format Kivy popup to eliminate popup background

Tags: python, kivy

we're using an image as a popup in our kivy app but can't seem to get the popup's background to fit the size of the image. The resulting popup has the image with a dark gray border around the left side, top, and right side of the image. Can someone help us eliminate the popup's background so that only the image and the semi-transparent filter are visible?

Main.py code:

```
popup = Popup(title="",
                  content=Image(source='img/popup'),
                  auto_dismiss=True,
                  size_hint=(None, None),
                  size=(400, 146),
                  separator_height=0
                  )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a title, maybe a simple ModalView would better fit your purposes.

Either way, the background is controlled by the `background` and `background_color` properties. To get rid of it entirely, it's probably simplest to set `popup.background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0)` (i.e. transparent).

Comment: thanks inclement - we couldn't get the transparent background to work but the ModalView solution worked like a charm!