# Transparent backing to center of kivy modalview widget

Tags: python-2.7, mobile, kivy

we're using a transparent image as a modalview popup in our kivy app but can't get the center image's backing to be transparent (or semi transparent like the background area around the center section of the modalview). The resulting popup has the image on a white rectangle that is then surrounded by the semi-transparent gray. Is there a way to make the white rectangle semi-transparent gray like the area that surrounds the center of the modalvieww popup?

Here is the modalview kv code:

```
<ScreenLoadingPopup>:
size_hint: .25, .20
BoxLayout:
    padding: [10,10,10,10]
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        source: 'img/transparent_loading.png'
        size_hint_y: None
```

To be clear, we're not trying to make the background surrounding the center modalview image transparent. That question was already asked and answered here [Format Kivy popup to eliminate popup background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026969/format-kivy-popup-to-eliminate-popup-background) Thanks in advance

Comment: Check that the image is truly transparent, and that you don't have any kv rules like `<BoxLayout>: canvas: Color: ... Rectangle: ...`

Comment: Thanks Ryan. We double checked. The image is truly transparent. However, you were right that the boxlayout we were using had a white canvas background. However, we fixed that too and changed it to a GridLayout but the rectangle continued to appear (albeit dark gray this time). In the end, we solved the problem by giving the popup a transparent background image as shown below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem by using a transparent image for the modalview background as shown below:

```
<ScreenLoadingPopup>:
size_hint: 0.25, 0.20
background: 'img/transparent_button1.png'
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    padding: [10,10,10,10]
    Image:
        source: 'img/loading_image.png'
        size: self.size
```